# Issue Installing Locustio(0.7.5) Package

Tags: python, django, gevent, locust

macOS == 10.15.7 || Django Project || Python 3.6.7

When I'm trying to install locustio version 0.7.5 package from pip it's giving error.I have tried the fixes mentioned in all the versions of answer that were similar to this everywhere but yet no progress.

When I run the following command :- pip install locustio==0.7.5

```
Collecting locustio==0.7.5
  Using cached locustio-0.7.5-py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.9.1 in /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from locustio==0.7.5) (2.25.1)
Collecting flask>=0.10.1
  Using cached Flask-1.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: msgpack-python>=0.4.2 in /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from locustio==0.7.5) (0.5.6)
Collecting gevent==1.1.1
  Using cached gevent-1.1.1.tar.gz (2.0 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet>=0.4.9 in /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from gevent==1.1.1->locustio==0.7.5) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from flask>=0.10.1->locustio==0.7.5) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from flask>=0.10.1->locustio==0.7.5) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from flask>=0.10.1->locustio==0.7.5) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from flask>=0.10.1->locustio==0.7.5) (2.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->flask>=0.10.1->locustio==0.7.5) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->locustio==0.7.5) (2020.12.5)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->locustio==0.7.5) (1.26.4)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->locustio==0.7.5) (2.10)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<5,>=3.0.2 in /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests>=2.9.1->locustio==0.7.5) (4.0.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: gevent
  Building wheel for gevent (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jl/3rfnlg653b59kb51g4xm_msm0000gp/T/pip-install-cznfaibp/gevent_7a86cd903b4e4364b7265e8b69a43703/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jl/3rfnlg653b59kb51g4xm_msm0000gp/T/pip-install-cznfaibp/gevent_7a86cd903b4e4364b7265e8b69a43703/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/jl/3rfnlg653b59kb51g4xm_msm0000gp/T/pip-wheel-7no23idl
       cwd: /private/var/folders/jl/3rfnlg653b59kb51g4xm_msm0000gp/T/pip-install-cznfaibp/gevent_7a86cd903b4e4364b7265e8b69a43703/
  Complete output (197 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/gevent
  copying gevent/queue.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/gevent
  copying gevent/greenlet.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/gevent
  ....
  running build_ext
  Running '(cd  "/private/var/folders/jl/3rfnlg653b59kb51g4xm_msm0000gp/T/pip-install-cznfaibp/gevent_7a86cd903b4e4364b7265e8b69a43703/libev"  && /bin/sh ./configure   && cp config.h "$OLDPWD" ) > configure-output.txt' in /private/var/folders/jl/3rfnlg653b59kb51g4xm_msm0000gp/T/pip-install-cznfaibp/gevent_7a86cd903b4e4364b7265e8b69a43703/build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/libev
  building 'gevent.corecext' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/gevent
  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -U__llvm__ -DLIBEV_EMBED=1 -DEV_COMMON= -DEV_CLEANUP_ENABLE=0 -DEV_EMBED_ENABLE=0 -DEV_PERIODIC_ENABLE=0 -Ibuild/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/libev -Ilibev -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include -I/Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c gevent/gevent.corecext.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/gevent/gevent.corecext.o
  In file included from gevent/gevent.corecext.c:241:
  In file included from gevent/libev.h:2:
  libev/ev.c:483:48: warning: '/*' within block comment [-Wcomment]
  /*#define MIN_INTERVAL  0.00000095367431640625 /* 1/2**20, good till 2200 */
                                                 ^
  libev/ev.c:1692:31: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
    EV_API_DECL struct ev_loop *ev_default_loop_ptr = 0; /* needs to be initialised to make it a definition despite extern */
                                ^
  libev/ev.c:1801:19: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-compare]
    if (elem * ncur > MALLOC_ROUND - sizeof (void *) * 4)
        ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  libev/ev.c:3715:34: warning: '&' within '|' [-Wbitwise-op-parentheses]
    fd_change (EV_A_ fd, w->events & EV__IOFDSET | EV_ANFD_REIFY);
                         ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~
  libev/ev.c:3715:34: note: place parentheses around the '&' expression to silence this warning
    fd_change (EV_A_ fd, w->events & EV__IOFDSET | EV_ANFD_REIFY);
                                   ^
                         (                      )
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:2276:138: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_1 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_3); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_3++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 121; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                           ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:2268:137: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_1 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_3); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_3++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 121; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                          
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3440:97: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'unsigned int' and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
    __pyx_t_1 = __pyx_f_6gevent_8corecext__flags_to_int(__pyx_v_flags, 0); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_1 == -1 && PyErr_Occurred())) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 161; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                        ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:435:43: note: expanded from macro 'unlikely'
    #define unlikely(x) __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)
                                            ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3713:140: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            __pyx_t_2 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_4, __pyx_t_5); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_5++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 194; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                             ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3705:139: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            __pyx_t_2 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_4, __pyx_t_5); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_5++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 194; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                            ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3927:138: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_1 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_3); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_3++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 201; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                           ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3919:137: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_1 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_3); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_3++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 201; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                          ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:4678:99: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'unsigned int' and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
      __pyx_t_2 = __pyx_f_6gevent_8corecext__flags_to_int(__pyx_v_flags, 0); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_2 == -1 && PyErr_Occurred())) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 260; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                          ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:435:43: note: expanded from macro 'unlikely'
    #define unlikely(x) __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)
                                            ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:5161:140: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            __pyx_t_6 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_3, __pyx_t_4); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_6); __pyx_t_4++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 294; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                             ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:5153:139: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            __pyx_t_6 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_3, __pyx_t_4); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_6); __pyx_t_4++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 294; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                            ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:8323:138: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_2 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_3, __pyx_t_4); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_4++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 465; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                           ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:8315:137: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
          __pyx_t_2 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_3, __pyx_t_4); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_4++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 465; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                          ^~~~~~~
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:43678:44: error: no member named 'tp_print' in 'struct _typeobject'
    __pyx_type_6gevent_8corecext__EVENTSType.tp_print = 0;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:43685:21: error: no member named 'tp_print' in 'struct _typeobject'
    PyGeventLoop_Type.tp_print = 0;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:43748:21: error: no member named 'tp_print' in 'struct _typeobject'
    PyGeventStat_Type.tp_print = 0;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:43752:60: error: no member named 'tp_print' in 'struct _typeobject'
    __pyx_type_6gevent_8corecext___pyx_scope_struct__genexpr.tp_print = 0;
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45511:21: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
      *type = tstate->exc_type;
              ~~~~~~  ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45512:22: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
      *value = tstate->exc_value;
                       ^~~~~~~~~
                       curexc_value
  /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/pystate.h:80:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_value;
                ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45513:19: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
      *tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                    curexc_traceback
  /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/pystate.h:81:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
      PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                ^
  gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45525:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
      tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                 ~~~~~~  ^
  fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
  20 warnings and 20 errors generated.
  error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gevent
  Running setup.py clean for gevent
Failed to build gevent
Installing collected packages: gevent, flask, locustio
  Attempting uninstall: gevent
    Found existing installation: gevent 21.1.2
    Uninstalling gevent-21.1.2:
      Successfully uninstalled gevent-21.1.2
    Running setup.py install for gevent ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jl/3rfnlg653b59kb51g4xm_msm0000gp/T/pip-install-cznfaibp/gevent_7a86cd903b4e4364b7265e8b69a43703/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jl/3rfnlg653b59kb51g4xm_msm0000gp/T/pip-install-cznfaibp/gevent_7a86cd903b4e4364b7265e8b69a43703/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/jl/3rfnlg653b59kb51g4xm_msm0000gp/T/pip-record-9h82uty_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/include/site/python3.9/gevent
         cwd: /private/var/folders/jl/3rfnlg653b59kb51g4xm_msm0000gp/T/pip-install-cznfaibp/gevent_7a86cd903b4e4364b7265e8b69a43703/
    Complete output (148 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    running build_ext
    Running '(cd  "/private/var/folders/jl/3rfnlg653b59kb51g4xm_msm0000gp/T/pip-install-cznfaibp/gevent_7a86cd903b4e4364b7265e8b69a43703/libev"  && /bin/sh ./configure   && cp config.h "$OLDPWD" ) > configure-output.txt' in /private/var/folders/jl/3rfnlg653b59kb51g4xm_msm0000gp/T/pip-install-cznfaibp/gevent_7a86cd903b4e4364b7265e8b69a43703/build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/libev
    building 'gevent.corecext' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/gevent
    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -U__llvm__ -DLIBEV_EMBED=1 -DEV_COMMON= -DEV_CLEANUP_ENABLE=0 -DEV_EMBED_ENABLE=0 -DEV_PERIODIC_ENABLE=0 -Ibuild/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/libev -Ilibev -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include -I/Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9 -c gevent/gevent.corecext.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-3.9/gevent/gevent.corecext.o
    In file included from gevent/gevent.corecext.c:241:
    In file included from gevent/libev.h:2:
    libev/ev.c:483:48: warning: '/*' within block comment [-Wcomment]
    /*#define MIN_INTERVAL  0.00000095367431640625 /* 1/2**20, good till 2200 */
                                                   ^
    libev/ev.c:1692:31: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
      EV_API_DECL struct ev_loop *ev_default_loop_ptr = 0; /* needs to be initialised to make it a definition despite extern */
                                  ^
    libev/ev.c:1801:19: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'unsigned long' [-Wsign-compare]
      if (elem * ncur > MALLOC_ROUND - sizeof (void *) * 4)
          ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    libev/ev.c:3715:34: warning: '&' within '|' [-Wbitwise-op-parentheses]
      fd_change (EV_A_ fd, w->events & EV__IOFDSET | EV_ANFD_REIFY);
                           ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~
    libev/ev.c:3715:34: note: place parentheses around the '&' expression to silence this warning
      fd_change (EV_A_ fd, w->events & EV__IOFDSET | EV_ANFD_REIFY);
                                     ^
                           (                      )
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:2276:138: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            __pyx_t_1 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_3); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_3++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 121; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                             ^~~~~~~
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:2268:137: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            __pyx_t_1 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_3); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_3++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 121; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                            ^~~~~~~
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:2664:138: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            __pyx_t_1 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_3); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_3++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 144; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                             ^~~~~~~
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:2656:137: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            __pyx_t_1 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_3); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_3++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 144; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                            ^~~~~~~
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3141:142: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
                __pyx_t_3 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_8, __pyx_t_9); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_3); __pyx_t_9++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 171; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L5_error;}
                                                                                                                                                 ^~~~~~~
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3133:141: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
                __pyx_t_3 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_8, __pyx_t_9); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_3); __pyx_t_9++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 171; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L5_error;}
                                                                                                                                                ^~~~~~~
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3440:97: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'unsigned int' and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
      __pyx_t_1 = __pyx_f_6gevent_8corecext__flags_to_int(__pyx_v_flags, 0); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_1 == -1 && PyErr_Occurred())) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 161; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                          ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:435:43: note: expanded from macro 'unlikely'
      #define unlikely(x) __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)
                                              ^
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3713:140: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              __pyx_t_2 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_4, __pyx_t_5); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_5++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 194; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                               ^~~~~~~
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3705:139: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              __pyx_t_2 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_4, __pyx_t_5); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_2); __pyx_t_5++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 194; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                              ^~~~~~~
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3927:138: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            __pyx_t_1 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_3); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_3++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 201; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                             ^~~~~~~
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:3919:137: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
            __pyx_t_1 = PyList_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_2, __pyx_t_3); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_3++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 201; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                            ^~~~~~~
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:4678:99: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'unsigned int' and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
        __pyx_t_2 = __pyx_f_6gevent_8corecext__flags_to_int(__pyx_v_flags, 0); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_2 == -1 && PyErr_Occurred())) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 260; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                            ~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:435:43: note: expanded from macro 'unlikely'
      #define unlikely(x) __builtin_expect(!!(x), 0)
                                              ^
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:5161:140: warning: code will never be executed [-Wunreachable-code]
              __pyx_t_6 = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(__pyx_t_3, __pyx_t_4); __Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_t_6); __pyx_t_4++; if (unlikely(0 < 0)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 294; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
                                                                                                                                              
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:43678:44: error: no member named 'tp_print' in 'struct _typeobject'
      __pyx_type_6gevent_8corecext__EVENTSType.tp_print = 0;
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:43685:21: error: no member named 'tp_print' in 'struct _typeobject'
      PyGeventLoop_Type.tp_print = 0;
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
      __pyx_type_6gevent_8corecext___pyx_scope_struct__genexpr.tp_print = 0;
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45511:21: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
        *type = tstate->exc_type;
                ~~~~~~  ^
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45512:22: error: no member named 'exc_value' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_value'?
        *value = tstate->exc_value;
                         ^~~~~~~~~
                         curexc_value
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/pystate.h:80:15: note: 'curexc_value' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_value;
                  ^
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45513:19: error: no member named 'exc_traceback' in 'struct _ts'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
        *tb = tstate->exc_traceback;
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
                      curexc_traceback
    /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/include/python3.9/cpython/pystate.h:81:15: note: 'curexc_traceback' declared here
        PyObject *curexc_traceback;
                  ^
    gevent/gevent.corecext.c:45525:24: error: no member named 'exc_type' in 'struct _ts'
        tmp_type = tstate->exc_type;
                   ~~~~~~  ^
    fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
    20 warnings and 20 errors generated.
    error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of gevent
  Moving to /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gevent-21.1.2.dist-info/
   from /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages/~event-21.1.2.dist-info
  Moving to /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gevent/
   from /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages/~event
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jl/3rfnlg653b59kb51g4xm_msm0000gp/T/pip-install-cznfaibp/gevent_7a86cd903b4e4364b7265e8b69a43703/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jl/3rfnlg653b59kb51g4xm_msm0000gp/T/pip-install-cznfaibp/gevent_7a86cd903b4e4364b7265e8b69a43703/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/jl/3rfnlg653b59kb51g4xm_msm0000gp/T/pip-record-9h82uty_/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/include/site/python3.9/gevent Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have also tried installing gevent separately but it also gets stuck.Can somebody please suggest some fix for this.

Answer (score 3):

You should install locust package it's not locustio anymore:

```
pip install locust
```

> Locust package has moved from 'locustio' to 'locust'. Please update
> your reference (or pin your version to 0.14.6 if you dont want to
> update to 1.0)

Answer (score 1):

Building on Vova's answer, the problem is most likely that you're using a current version of Python with very old packages. The [gevent 1.1.1](https://www.gevent.org/whatsnew_1_1.html#broader-platform-support) page (the version you're trying to install) says that it supports Python 3.3 and 3.4; you're using 3.9 (`/Users/anantkrishanjoshi/.virtualenvs/envdoconpy/lib/python3.9/site-packages`), not the 3.6.7 you think.

You'll need to either downgrade your Python version or use a much newer version of gevent/Locust.